# Возможно ли объявить (на ходу) вектор заданной размерности?

Tags: c++

Допустим программа, во время ее исполнения, получает некоторое числовое значение N, по которому следует "построить" вектор  N размерности (то бишь `::std::vector<::std::vector<...::std::vector<T>...>`). Можно ли как-то это реализовать и, если возможно, то как? Может если для данного примера с `vector` это никак не сделать, то с помощью чего можно реализовать такую идею?
Я предполагаю, должно быть что-то в духе:

```
template<int Size, typename T>  
decltype(auto) outType()  
{  
    if (Size <= 0) return ::std::vector<T>();  
    return outType<Size - 1, ::std::vector<T>>();  
}
```

Comment: так как вы привели не получится - шаблоны это фишка времени компиляции, а не исполнения

Comment: вместо этого вы можете попробовать сделать кое что другое: выделить массив линейно и задать ему размерности. Ну а к элементам обращаться соответственно этим размерам. Так, по сути, сделано в OpenCV например

Comment: Проблемы начинаются: когда вы повсеместно, для каждой задачи, используете вектор. Это я наблюдал у многих. Не нужно игнорировать другие средства стандартной библиотеки, которые предназначены именно для выбора под задачу. В вашем случаи, например, больше подойдет std::valarray. Вы можете создать его любого размера, а потом обращаться к любым срезам.

Answer (score 2):

если `N` - константа, известная во время компиляции, то такую вещь провернуть еще можно было бы,

но во время выполнения, когда программа уже скомпилирована, многомерный вектор придется создавать руками, т.е. рекурсивным вызовом

да и по хорошему вместо многомерного вектора всегда можно создать одномерный вектор, только индекс придется вычислять самому (например вместо двумерного вектора зачастую удобнее иметь одномерный размером `MxN`, где `index = i + j * M`)

Comment: думаю, хорошая идея, спасибо. Тем не менее, хочется узнать, можно ли реализовать это в тип, чтобы далее "хорошо" обращаться через операторы к нему

Comment: @dreamIIx, думаю динамически нет, только самому создавать

Answer (score 0):

Для ограниченного набора случаев подобную задачу можно решить перебором всех случаев в рантайме, примерно так:

```
switch(dim)
{
case 1: process<1>(...);
case 2: process<2>(...);
...
```

Копипасту можно убрать шаблонным и/или препроцессорным метапрограмммированием.

В общем случае, нельзя воплотить неограниченное (или слишком большое) число вариантов шаблона